# Creating a Instant Messaging using HTTP & JSON

Tags: android, json, http, instant-messaging

Can anyone guide me or provide a link so that i can move forward. how I can do instant messaging in app. I want to send the message to server from one device & from server i should get back on other device in JSON format using HTTP. I have gone through many sites but dint get proper ideas. so please if you know give me some ideas.

many thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the IM app..

```
step 1 : Send the msg to server as a json object to server.
step 2 : keep running response thread for every seconds.
step 3 : Server sends the msg to requested user as a json object.
step 4 : server takes the msg from requested user and sends back as a response. which is running on other thread.
```

Comment: @BenCheng for TCP protocol WebSocket will be alternative.